# learning to use pthread, what's the correct syntax to pass a pthread as a parameter when calling function master_Level()?

Tags: c++, pthreads

something I tried,

```
error: pthreads undeclared
```

mostly confused about how to pass the pthreads correctly in each part marked in comments

```cpp
      int main(){
          ...
          pthread_t p_threads[4];
          int level= 10 ;
          int idx  = 1 ;
          master_Level(head,level, idx, p_threads);  
          ...
     }



     void master_Level(node* root,int level, int idx, pthread_t* p_theads){
        if (root == NULL){
            return;
        }
        if (level == 1){
            pthread_create(&p_threads[idx], NULL, (void*)&hashtree,(void*)&root);                             
            // part1
            idx+=1;
        }
        if (level > 1){
            master_Level(root->left, level-1, idx, p_threads); 
            master_Level(root->right, level-1,idx, p_threads);
        }
    }

    unsigned char* hashTree(node* curr){
        ...
    }
```

Comment: The array declaration has an underscore.

Comment: thanks man, I . tried adding underscore for the others, but part 1 is still undeclared for the &p_threads[idx]

Comment: You haven't declared `p_threads` (nor `pthreads`) in the function `master_Level`.

Comment: is there any suggestion that I could some how to call pthread_create(&p_threads[idx], ...)?

Comment: You either have not posted the latest piece of code, or you only pasted part of it. "pthreads" does not appear in your code at all...

Comment: Do you have a reason not to use `std:: thread`? It's simpler and cross platform

Comment: Your argument in `master_Level` is called `p_theads` not `p_threads`